# Fit more than one block of data from the same file

Tags: gnuplot

I have these two blocks of data in the same file. Both represents a set of measurements that I want to fit then using a single script to compare each other. I know that it would be easier separate in two files and than fit each one separately but I'll have more than two blocks and it would be boring. Someone know how should I do it?.

I tried to use:

```
f(x) = a*x^b
f1(x) = a1*x^b1
fit f(x) "temp.dat" i 0 u 1:2:4 via a,b, f1(x) "temp.dat" i 1 u 1:2:4 via a1,b1

p f(x), "temp.dat" i 0 u 1:2:4 w yer, f1(x), "temp.dat" i 1 u 1:2:4
```

Thks

```
1 100    2.13048e-09   0.2   2.4178e-11
2 140    1.51668e-09   0.2   1.69698e-11
3 180    1.18001e-09   0.2   1.35081e-11
4
5 100    1.41599e-09   0.3   1.62087e-11
6 140    1.02526e-09   0.3   1.16511e-11
7 180    8.1794e-10    0.3   9.50745e-12
```

Comment: Oops, You forgot to post your code and required output. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your data file blocks should be separated by two blank lines in order to use the `index` option. Otherwise, with only one blank line, you need to use `every`.

That said, what you want to achieve can be done with `eval` and a `do for` loop:

```
do for [i=0:1] {
eval sprintf("f%i(x) = a%i + b%i * x", i, i, i)
eval sprintf("fit f%i(x) 'temp.dat' i %i via a%i, b%i", i, i, i, i)
}

plot "temp.dat" i 0, f0(x), "temp.dat" i 1, f1(x)
```

[image]